# How to install the app with its data using .bak files

Tags: applications, backup, xiaomi, miui, redmi-note-4

**Background**

I created a local backup of my apps in my Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 before installing another MIUI ROM.

**Problem**

During transfer of that backup to PC or some other way(I don't know how!) the **descript.xml** file is missing from backup folder so now the local backup app in phone isn't showing the files for restore.

**Question** ***(HELP NEEDED WITH)***

1. How to create the descript.xml file?

***OR***

2. I checked the layout of file by taking a short settings feature backup and seeing its XML file but it's very complicated and requires a lot of information about .bak file!..Can anyone share a layout type so that I can create a .XML file?

***OR***

3. Suggest any app that converts .bak files to apk with keeping there data. Or installs the bak files directly as apps in phone!

---

I really need those apps data. Its really important.

Comment: I assume you were using some Xiaomi tool for creating the backup. Does this tool run on-device or on your PC?

Comment: @Robert the tool is available  for backup to local storage in settings app itself. I don't think it can be used in PC.